# detect Overlap two circle in javascript

Tags: javascript, geometry, overlap

I have a loop with php that make circles with canvas html 5.
And the position of the circles are random like this code:

```
ctx.arc( Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1), Math.floor((Math.random()*500)+1), <?php echo $size ?>, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
```

but now I have an problem.
My circles are overlap.
I want that they haven't any overlap.
What should I do?

Comment: Store the positions in an array and simply check if any of them intersect before making a new one. If they're all the same size (radius), then you only need the positions.

Comment: They haven't the same size.We can save the position in an array.but already there is some problem. I want that they can be like this: http://vallandingham.me/vis/gates/

Comment: and I want that they have more distance than the link